Assign same value to 2 columns in a select query
Consider the following query
SELECT x + 2 AS d, x + 2 AS e FROM y;
Can I assign same value to d and e without repeating x + 2. Assume x + 2 is some complex operation.
I can achieve this using CTE but cannot use it.
I'm using postgres.

Which postgresql version you are using ?

Could you maybe share this complex operation ? not clear why you need this !

I'm using 15.4.1.

Sorry, not possible to share the operation. I want this so I don't have to duplicate that operation in the query.

I don't believe this is possible. Some DBMSs support syntax like this: SELECT x + 2 AS d, d AS e FROM y; but PostgreSQL doesn't (as far as I know). However, the query optimiser may be clever enough to recognise this is the same calculation and so only perform it once.

Why can't you use a CTE? How about a subquery where you establish that equation and then re-use that in your select list: SELECT d, d as e FROM y, LATERAL(SELECT x+2)AS subquery(d); demo. In psql you can also use \set d x+2. Or, you can wrap that equation in a SQL function and use that.


Put the equation in a lateral subquery and then re-use that in your select list: demo
SELECT d, d as e 
FROM y, LATERAL(SELECT x+2)AS subquery(d);


In psql you can also use
\set d x+2:
\set d x+2
SELECT :d, :d as e 
FROM y;


Wrap that equation in a SQL function and use that:
create function d(x int)returns int return x+2;
SELECT d(x), d(x) as e 
FROM y;


If you don't want to use a CTE because you suspect it'll be re-evaluated multiple times for some reason, you can use materialized to make sure that doesn't happen.
WITH cte AS MATERIALIZED(SELECT x+2 as d,* FROM y)
SELECT d, d as e, *
FROM cte;



Even if you repeat an expression over and over again, PostgreSQL can and will spot the repetition, evaluate it only once and re-use the result. While all of these could help clean up and shorten your code a bit, don't expect any performance gains compared to the repetitive version.
